# Does sending POST data to a server that doesn't accept post data recieve the data?

Tags: http, api, post

I am setting up a back end API in a script of mine that contacts one of my sites by sending XML to my web server in the form of POST data.  This script will be used by many and I want to limit the bandwidth waste for people that accidentally turn the feature on without a proper access key.

I will be denying requests that do not have the correct access key by maybe generating a 403 access code.

Lets say the POST data is ~500kb of data.  Does the server receive all 500kb of data when this attempt is made regardless of the status code?

How about if I made the url contain the key mydomain/api/123456789 and generate 403 status on all bad access keys.

Does the POST data still get sent/received regardless or is it negotiated before the data is finally sent.

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Generally speaking, the entire request *will* be sent, including post data. There is often no way for the application layer to return a response like a 403 until it has received the entire request.

In reality, it will depend on the language/framework used and how closely it is linked to the HTTP server. [Section 8.2.2 of RFC2616 HTTP/1.1 specification](http://www.w3.org/Protocols/rfc2616/rfc2616-sec8.html#sec8.2.2) has this to say

> An HTTP/1.1 (or later) client sending
>   a message-body SHOULD monitor the
>   network connection for an error status
>   while it is transmitting the request.
>   If the client sees an error status, it
>   SHOULD immediately cease transmitting
>   the body. If the body is being sent
>   using a "chunked" encoding (section
>   3.6), a zero length chunk and empty trailer MAY be used to prematurely
>   mark the end of the message. If the
>   body was preceded by a Content-Length
>   header, the client MUST close the
>   connection.

So, if you can find a language environemnt closely linked with the HTTP server (for example, mod_perl), you could do this in a way which does comply with standards.

An alternative approach you could take is to make an initial, smaller request to obtain a URL to use for the larger POST. The application can then deny providing the URL to clients without an appropriate key.

Comment: Depending on the actual framework used to read the actual request nd write the reply, it is technically conceivable to read just the request headers, validate access, and if denied then send back a reply right away and close the connection without ever reading the actual post data.

Comment: That's true, I've beefed up the answer to show that it is possible to do this and comply with the HTTP/1.1 standards.

Answer (score 0):

Here is great book about RESTful Web Services, where it's explained how HTTP works: http://oreilly.com/catalog/9780596529260

You can consider any request as envelope, where on top of it it's written address (URL), some properties (HTTP Headers) and inside it there's some data (if request is initiated by post method). So as you might guess you can't receive envelope partially.

Oh I forgot, it's when you are using HTTP Post with standard HTTP header "application/x-www-form-urlencoded" but if you are uploading files (correspondingly using ""multipart/form-data") Django gives you control over streamed chunks of files using Middleware classes: http://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/http/middleware/